# Fragility of using Excel Object Library in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, export-to-excel, win32com

A bit of preface: this project, while technically homework, is completely under my 5-man team's control. We came up with the project, defined the scope, and exercise full creative control. So it's not traditional homework, it's equivalent to a senior project.

One of the outputs of the system I'm developing should be very similar to a well formatted Excel spreadsheet. We could create (or find) a graphics library and handle the printing in our own code... but ultimately we feel that an Excel spreadsheet file will be more portable. As the user can open it up in Excel, edit it, e-mail it, etc.

Accessing Excel programatically seems simple enough (i.e: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302094)

But my question is: what happens when "Office 2013" comes out, and the user removes Office 2010 and installs 2013?

I won't be around to maintain this project... and I'd hate to force someone into opening up my code just to reference the Excel 13.0 COM.

I'll be using incredibly basic functions of the API.
So long as I can read-and-write to a range of cells, and adjust the interior color of cells, my code will work.

In general, how can I make my VB.Net code access whatever Microsoft Excel API is available on the target system? (Including future Excel APIs.)

Comment: Excel.Application has referred to which ever version of Excel is installed for quite some time at this stage. There is no reference to version number in that.

Comment: To reference the KB link in my post: "On the COM tab, locate Microsoft Excel Object Library, and then click Select." -- The COM tab shows specific version numbers, this is the version number I'm worried about. Does that not need to reflect the installed version of Office on the client machine, just the dev. machine?

Comment: Have you though about outputting the data in a cvs file instead? That way your user is not locked to excel at all

Comment: Consider late binding: http://www.developerdotstar.com/community/node/717/print

Comment: @Ralph: We need to do some color coding, and other formatting. These are "pretty print" documents, so to speak - CSV really can't provide the output we're hoping to achieve.

Comment: I've written quite a bit of code for generating documents, and use various third party libraries - 1 for writing xls(x) files, and a couple of different ones for generating PDFs.  The PDF libraries are quite good at tabular output, and will do the obvious formatting.  I've also used the approach you describe, and do have some code from _years_ ago against Excel 2000 which will still run against later versions.  But in the end I found it slow, flaky, prone to security issues - I'd suggest having a look at other components you could use

Comment: Unfortunately, users love Excel.  However in terms of deployment, it boils down to licencing on projects I've been involved with for many clients in the past.  As Stu said, PDF generation is a good alternative - I'm currently working on PDF Sharp (http://www.pdfsharp.net/) which seems quite neat at first use.  And you can normally copy tables to Excel.  I've also used quite a lot of transforming XML to HTML via XSLT - where you could add colours and styles...  Just an offtopic thought

Answer (score 1):

I recommend first developing using the Excel PIA (Primary Interop Assemblies) so you get autocomplete and online help in Visual Studio.

Once your program is complete, I recommend switching to late-binding before publishing, so your EXE works with different versions of Excel.

1. Develop first using the current Excel PIA until it works as you
   want (Google "Excel PIA" to download the assemblies)
2. When your program is complete, add `Option Strict Off` to the top of the modules that use Excel objects
3. Replace all Excel PIA classes with `Object` e.g.
   `Dim xls As Excel.Application` 
   becomes
   `Dim xls As Object`
4. Replace 
   `xls = New Excel.Application`
   with 
   `xls = CreateObject("Excel.Application")`
5. Remove the Excel PIA reference and tidy up